# OS X Server DNS management

Tags: dns, server, dns-servers, nameserver, apple

I have an OS X 10.6 Server running, which has PHP, Apache, MySQL, and DNS running on it. I want to take the DNS management out of the Server Admin App. I know that the DNS configuration files (the ones BIND uses) are plain text files (which have to obey some rules, obviously).

The main reason for this is because I wanted to setup DKIM for one of my domains, and I had to add a TXT record to the subdomain pm._domainkey.example.com. Server Admin did not let me add that subdomain, because of the "invalid" underscore character.

I searched for web based DNS management tools (the ones that I would install on my server and would allow me to manage my DNS records), but I couldn't find any good ones. (There were a couple that I managed to install, but they didn't see the configuration that I already had setup in Server Admin). Now I'm looking into editing the config files directly, but I don't know where they're located.

This is a test / development server, so messing it up wouldn't be such a disaster. I know "I shouldn't do this", but I want to :).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

/var/named/zones is where the zone files should be kept per [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2259058?start=0&tstart=0).

I looked around for a good example of a how the structure should be and actually the best I found on quick review was on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file).